# Convert an Integer to its Hex value in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

The decimal value 100 has a hex value of 64 as seen [here](http://www.ascii-code.com/). How can I convert 100 to that hex value? I have tried

```
a = bytes([64])
```

but that returns

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

(a `bytes` object with a length of 64) not what I want.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

Your copied output is wrong, compare [`bytes([source[, encoding[, errors]]])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes):

```
In [1]: bytes([64])
Out[1]: b'@'
```

As opposed to:

```
In [2]: bytes(64)
Out[2]: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

To convert an integer `v` to a hex string, use: [`hex(v)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex)

```
In [3]: hex(100)
Out[3]: '0x64'
```

Comment: Don't know how that happened. This is the solution, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
'{:x}'.format(100)
```

Comment: IMHO, a bit more "readable" option can be `'0x{:X}'.format(100)` (notice X is in uppercase). For `2034` it will print `0x7F2` instead of `7f2`.

Comment: @PavelSapehin: If you like that format, use `'{:#X}'`.  The hash on the front makes it print in the "alternate" form with a `0x` prefix.

Comment: Thanks, that's cool addition! However, it prints '0X7F2' where `X` is in uppercase. Is there an option to print `0x` where `x` is in lowercase and the rest of the HEX in uppercase?

Answer (score 1):

In python hex is inbuilt function to convert integer to hex value you can try:
hex(100)
will give you result:
'0x64'